# Very minor formatting issue

Tags: bug, profile-page

I think this a bug, and maybe should be corrected:
[image: bug]

See the email address? If it's quite long, it gets cut off...

Why can't it just go to a new line? or even elegantly fall-back with `clip` or something?

Very minor, but I think it's worth noting and possibly fixing. :)

Comment: Mailinator? I look forward to seeing your new gravatars.

Comment: I sense the presence of a large S somewhere nearby ...

Comment: Sorry I got banned: I'm the OP of this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

Meh, most users emails aren't this long, and all it takes to select is a double-click.

Besides the only time mods are going to send you an email is going to be through the mod-message interface, so at the end of the day you're the only one that it matters to.

My advice is to pick a shorter email address.

Comment: thx for the answer. :)